# X is related posteriorly to Y

Tags: meaning

"X is posterior to Y" means "X is behind Y".

So if the statement is "X is related posteriorly to Y", does it mean:

- "X is behind Y" or
- "Y is behind X"?

As for "Posteriorly, X is related to Y", does it mean:

- "X is behind Y" or
- "Y is behind X"?

Thank you for your explanation.

Edit:

These sentences were written as such in several anatomy textbooks.

Eg 1 "The iliopsoas is related anteriorly to the fascia lata and the femoral artery, and posteriorly to the capsule of the hip joint."

Eg 2 "Sigmoid and rectum are related anteriorly to the bladder."

Eg 3 "Medially, this muscle is related to the bodies of the lumbar vertebrae and vessels." (My interpretation: The muscle is on the outer/lateral side whereas the vertebrae/vessels are on the inner/medial side).

In Eg 1, the usage of "related anteriorly to" in this sentence seems to imply that the iliopsoas is in between the fascia lata/femoral artery and the hip joint, whereas, in Eg 2, the sentence seems to mean that the bladder is in front of the sigmoid and rectum.

However, if "related anteriorly to" means the same as "anterior to"/"in front of", then these sentences would be wrong, wouldn't they? 
Eg 1 would instead mean the iliopsoas is in front of the fascia lata/femoral artery but behind the hip joint.
Eg 2 would instead mean sigmoid/rectum are in front of the bladder.

Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: It could mean a number of things. You'll need to provide context to narrow it down.

Comment: The first case is fairly clearcut: X is behind Y. The second case is unclear. But is 'posteriorly' (a horrible word in my opinion) being used literally or metaphorically? [In philosophy, "a posteriori' is (or was) used to mean something like 'known by experience of the world'.]

Comment: This doesn't sound natural.  Usually "posterior" means *fanny* (body part).  Where did you find this?

Comment: It looks as if "related posteriorly" might be a bit of specialist terminology. I am more puzzled by what "related" means in this context (and how it can be either anteriorly or posteriorly). Is there a medical Stack Exchange? EDIT: Yes, you could try asking here: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com

Comment: @aparente001 I doubt that is the *usual*, or most common, meaning of posterior. And just a note/warning that fanny means something *very* different in UK English. (More anterior than the US meaning.)

Comment: In fact the meaning is **so** different that I nearly deleted that comment, @aparente001.

Comment: @TrevorD Those are just examples. What I'm asking is NOT where the muscle is but the usage of "related posteriorly/anteriorly to" because it is different from what I understand it to be.

Comment: @chaegyeong Sorry if I caused offense. My point was that I'm unaware of such terminology being used other than in anatomy, and that in such circumstances confusing which item is behind the other could be disastrous. Also, certain terminology can have a specialised meaning in a particular area of science, etc.. In those circumstances, it seemed to me to be inappropriate to be asking it in a general language forum.

Comment: Noted. Thank you everyone for your response.

Comment: @aparente001 "Posterior" is a standard anatomical directional term, the opposite direction of anterior. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location

Comment: @BryanKrause - okay, but "related posteriorly" sounds awful.  Is it some acceptable technical phrase that you've come across?

Comment: @aparente001 No, it's terrible and probably archaic but does appear in many texts, you can google the phrase and you will find it used consistently in the cases where it is used. The typical way in normal everyday scientific English is to say something is "posterior to" something else (see DoctorWhom's answer), which means what it sounds like, rather than this weird way of talking that's opposite.

Answer (score 4):

Anterior and posterior are anatomical terms used across the sciences, particularly in anatomy.  Anterior roughly means towards the front of the body; posterior, towards the back.  (The actual definition is a little more complex but this is sufficient.)

These are the planes of the body with directional terminology:

[image]

The problem is, adding "related...to" in these examples is converting these into the OPPOSITE meaning.

Looking at anatomical position, clearly the bladder is anterior to the rectum:

[image]

The way your text uses it would mean that these two sentences are equivalent:

- The rectum is related anteriorly to the bladder.
- The bladder is located anteriorly to the rectum.

This is confusing and the usage simply seems wrong.  But if you have found this in an actual medical text, it appears that this may be either (1) a poor translation into English, or (2) archaic terminology no longer used, or (3) a regional phrasing.

HOWEVER, when looking for a diagram, I came across this interesting slide from an unknown contributor, which uses "related to" to mean "attached to" or "sharing an anatomical boundary" without using the directional "anteriorly" terminology:

[image]

To me, this suggests that in some regions or contexts, it may be a way of phrasing that two things share an anatomical boundary, or lie against one another.  Again, it is rather odd sounding or perhaps archaic, and the added directional terminology makes it seem to say the opposite. However, apparently it does exist in some contexts.  I will update this if I run into any more clear explanations.